# Plugin get event before opening node

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I'm using [jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/) plugin for creating a tree of items. I need to make some actions before node opens, but I don't know which event is fired before node opening.

When node finished opening, jsTree plugin fires event `'open_node.jstree'`. Maybe there are some event which is fired before node opens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    $("#demo2").bind("before.jstree", function (e, data) {
        if(data.func === "open_node") {
            $("#log2").html(data.args[0].attr("id"));
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            return false;
        }
    });
});

reference: http://www.jstree.com/documentation/core#
```